# Exponential is differentiable at $0$, with $\sup$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and $$e^x=\sup\{e^r\mid r\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ and } r<x\}$$
We can easily prove that $e^x=\sup\{e^r\mid r<x\}$.
I want to show that, with this definition
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$$

---

The next part is false, so I want to focus in the first part...

More in general, if $u>1$ is fixed, with this definition:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u^h-1}{h}=1$$

Is there any way I could do it like that, without using other definitions of $e^x$?

Comment: The second limit equation isn't true.  For $u>0$, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u^h - 1}{h} = \ln u.$$

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Then only the first.

Comment: @SammyBlack the second should be true.... $\ln e = 1$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry, I erased the second part, I have put it back to note what was Sammy Black talking about.

Comment: How about showing that $e^x = \lim_n (1+ {x \over n})^n$ first?